# 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.' Cannot insert data into database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

I am creating a register form for a program however i cannot get the username and password to save into the microsoft access database. I do not see where i am going wrong with my code, i keep getting 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.' Here is my code...

```
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Users (username, password) VALUES (" & Me.Usernametxtb.Text & "','" & Me.Passwordtxtb.Text & "')"

        Dim cms As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        cms.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Usernametxtb.Text)
        cms.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Passwordtxtb.Text)
        cms.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: You are inserting the values directly in your query without an opening single quote. You probably meant to do something like this `INSERT INTO Users (username, password) VALUES (@username, @password)` (Might be different. You don't show what language you are using or anything.)

Comment: i've created a form using vb.net, i'm taking the values of the username and password directly from a textbox displayed on the form which the user fills out

Answer (score 1):

You are adding parameters, but your statement is not parameterised. Without referencing those parameters in the SQL statement using `@username`, they aren't used anywhere. The first line is still vulnerable to SQL injection because you're concatenating raw user input.

Also, [do not store passwords in plaintext, ever.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/)

Comment: Apart from what you mention, OP is adding single quotation marks around parameter values in his query. I don't know if this is correct (code samples I've found don't include any) but if it was, still wouldn't work as there is a missing quotation mark before first parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

And *Password* is a reserved word in Access, so try:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Users (username, [password]) VALUES (@username, @password)"

Dim cms As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
cms.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Usernametxtb.Text)
cms.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Passwordtxtb.Text)
cms.ExecuteNonQuery()
```